# ffmpeg - Change color of transparent pixels?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, pixels

Background:

When you turn pixels transparent, you're in fact just setting the alpha value of a pixel to 00. Said pixel can still have an arbitrary colour, no matter if it's green, blue, black or something completely different.

My question:

I got a video that's having a lot of "transparent-green" pixels, that all have the RGBA colour 00D70000. I need a way to convert all those transparent-green pixels into transparent-black, with the RGBA value 00000000.

How would I accomplish this using ffmpeg? Other command line tools would be fine as well, as long as they aren't a hassle to set up...

Comment: Can you please share more details? What type of codec and container are you using? (I was thinking about `vp9` and `WebM`, but then the pixel format is `yuva420p`, not `rgba`). Is there any video input sample we can download? Do you want to convert only the transparent-green pixels to transparent-black, or all the transparent pixels to transparent-black? Are there any semi-transparent pixels?

Comment: I was thinking about a solution. Are you no longer interested?